# Why is it all RSA algorithms, but the results are completely different?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I am learning rsa encryption and decryption recently. I try to encrypt some data in C# and verify the result. I found that the output result of the code I wrote in C# is inconsistent with the output result of some RSA online computing websites. Is this normal?

First I generated private key and public key using openssl:

private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXAIBAAKBgQDTlCZFucurE+QNupniPUXz5RwNdhRAplB+jd51U4NTcpDl4AL3
LppKdRxEyt4FlvLiE66tmonEJTc4BcaRurxxXOuY+0IS4l28FynYT/yDpdoiop0J
f2NCa8V5nCBISKp1Lgvz7AbHBw+3KNCF1UdrOeRsr/GBOSXosmTzPMRUNwIDAQAB
AoGALyDC3akjCrplhAFaoaBQYqFX/E+e9z+Uknv7X1r416+fQvUA9Bo3V/p6D4C4
r7oN4/nKYPUZVs2LXTk8H93ed2IikcevB4vnHgO3ym5vt+KyrmCemwyV/rbA5kg5
sDvMqXJr2/FfQtLR3GLumZJN2r5Hcq1Kgo3tgx7gsoZm4JECQQDxCoSeyWPuyQKx
3aHWJkVybmHD5d6HuFFyaM4pOAOXaGrtkZSrh3c+NJhAuW62d+oE8kwCNymz74G5
Pq+5yRftAkEA4LWOGKAeidLFM2RON3DFMNDH3KEB4C9144SilzVr6dDEOgBqdCya
+vazx2J0OV8Bm5ocqtTBOT4ZmD7BXtTQMwJASEwYVSwgnjmKZmEMrpfSEq2LA2AK
K/kb7M4EsBZN9XbrQ5B74CsEmBLca+VykKZM+ejW5X84MfEvnqlvubDYTQJBAKAv
7OcTJhH8JcY4CCYvhvMAsqlOQecODk0t3TZLx+z7fRcX+stsjOLBAXHudon7d0r0
duE1H7Vt1pMYkYLH1M8CQEZ76ME68DE7DkTPhBvPL22O898Kt89bCen68EVv3kl8
7k4XsAGrLldX6xvV/oeLDI+uRiYqZylS2PFY3XcT3f8=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

public key :

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDTlCZFucurE+QNupniPUXz5RwN
dhRAplB+jd51U4NTcpDl4AL3LppKdRxEyt4FlvLiE66tmonEJTc4BcaRurxxXOuY
+0IS4l28FynYT/yDpdoiop0Jf2NCa8V5nCBISKp1Lgvz7AbHBw+3KNCF1UdrOeRs
r/GBOSXosmTzPMRUNwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

this is my test c# codes:

```
string InputText = "ABCDEFG123456";

{
    string sk = File.ReadAllText("D:\\rsa_private_key.pem");
    string sk2 = sk.Replace("\n", "");

    var rsa = RSA.Create();

    rsa.ImportFromPem(sk.ToArray());
    var text = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InputText), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1));

    Console.WriteLine(text);

}
```

the output is :

```
WecnM6F8+oVuOR7OhOMeDwzrfWsYeW0uTMZC2AJ9a6AhzVIZgPhVZv1heMPN8yfhnBo03Vh/hzUXGeUZpAO7PVQ7mFKCRARy35cTcGxTpGLEhhAUe1cqj92rO5zlm/fIQOi0PraeduqD2HRQOSHz3eq71oHdy22s5sb4WNwyTj8=
```

Then, I did the same again on [this site](https://www.javainuse.com/rsagenerator):

[image]

the output is :

```
btZnhouzYuYk3grzhI9MJinlrmRmsVhmUBUpW0pKpXXZ2VPgw97Cx869+r7WMDQFRG34jELDIpeADNxJeUnnOwm1J5z489THaYO6pqQ7UWeXyMhus05RSPcNDjvJjjJcZ/FyxUNhd7JNqaioTQB8SKo+p3BD/VkMH0tl/I90WTc=
```

In addition, I also tested it on some other tools, and their output is consistent with the website, and inconsistent with my demo, so I want to ask, what is wrong with my C# code?
Or is the rsa encryption algorithm itself not stable?

One difference I can think of might be that the private key I pasted into the website is a string with newlines stripped.

Comment: RSA encryption includes random padding (i.e. `RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1`) which makes the output different every time. This is by design and is important for security.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk that could probably stand to be expanded into an answer. It isn't obvious why the "other tools" are producing a consistent result in that case, nor how practical programs are intended to deal with/account for the padding. (This question also needs a better title, but I can't figure out how to write it.)

Comment: thank you. I use openssl, RSA_private_encrypt, it generate a same result.

Comment: I should have read your code more carefully because I made the mistake of assuming you were really encrypting data rather than what you're actually doing (or attempting to do) which is *signing*.

Comment: The website does not adhere to the PKCS#1 v1.5 standard, as the message is neither hashed nor a digest ID is considered. Since the native C# methods (`SignData()` and `SignHash()`) only implement the standard, it is not possible to create the same signature with them. But C#/BouncyCastle allows this e.g. with `SignerUtilities.GetSigner("NoneWithRSA")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use openssl, it generate the same result with the website:

```
std::string decrypt_string(const void* data, size_t length)
{
    BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(pk.c_str(), (int)pk.size());
    
    RSA* rsa = NULL;
    PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(bio, &rsa, 0, 0);
    
    char buf[1024] = {0};
    
    int ret = RSA_public_decrypt(0x80, (const unsigned char*)data, (unsigned char*)buf, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    
    if(ret == -1)
    {
        BIO_free(bio);
        
        printf("decrypt error:%d\n", ret);
        return "Error";
    }
    
    BIO_free(bio);
    
    std::string str = buf;
    
    return buf;
}

std::string encrypt_string(const std::string& str)
{
    RSA* rsa = NULL;
    BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(sk.c_str(), (int)sk.size());
    
    PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio, &rsa, 0,0);
    
    assert(rsa!=NULL);
    
    char buf[1024];
    int ret = RSA_private_encrypt((int)str.length(), (const unsigned char *)str.data(), (unsigned char*)buf, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    
    if(ret == -1)
    {
        BIO_free(bio);
        
        printf("decrypt error:%d\n", ret);
        return "Error";
    }
    
    BIO_free(bio);
    
    std::string str2 = base64_encode((unsigned char const*)buf, ret);
    
    return str2;
}
```

Comment: If you "encrypt" with the private key then everyone can decrypt, rendering the operation useless. That's why the correct term for "encrypting" with the private key is *signing*.

Comment: Thank you, although this operation is strange, it is exactly the result I need. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Because `rsa.Encrypt` function preprocess the plaintext before applying the RSA function.

```
Enc(m; K) = R(pre(m),K)

Dec(c; k) = post(R(c,k))

OAEP-pre(m):
r = **random nonce**

X = (m || 00...0) XOR H(r) // pad m with zeros

Y = r XOR H(X)

output X || Y
```

Visit https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5430/2015sp/notes/rsa_sign_vs_dec.php